# mysqli php file doesn't recognise a variable from another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display data on a table from the database. To do this I made a date.php file to select a date and send that value to another select.php file that will allow me to select only data that has the same date on the data base. but the problem is that the file select.php can not recognize this value. I even tried to do SELECT * FROM archireunion ORDER BY datereunion DESC WHERE datereunion='2017-10-23' which exist on the database but it doesn't work.
help me please

date.php
This code allows me to get a date, then send it to the index.php file but the select.php file doesn't recognise the variable

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type=date value="madate">
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
</form>
```

index.php    all  functions are in this file

```
<html>
      <head>
           <title>Liste des réunions</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
           <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="table-responsive">
                     <h3 align="center">Liste des réunions</h3><br />
                     <div id="live_data"></div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </body>
 </html>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      function fetch_data()
      {
          //var date1 = $_GET['madate']
           $.ajax({
                url:"select.php",
                method:"POST",
                //data:{date:date},
                success:function(data){
                     $('#live_data').html(data);
                }
           });
      }
      fetch_data();
      $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
           var titre = $('#titre').text();
           var datereunion = $('#datereunion').text();
           var description = $('#description').text();

           if(titre == '')
           {
                alert("Entrer le titre de la réunion");
                return false;
           }
           if(datereunion == '')
           {
                alert("Entrer la date de la réunion");
                return false;
           }
           if(description == '')
           {
                alert("Entrer la description de la réunion ");
                return false;
           }
           $.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{titre:titre, datereunion:datereunion, description:description},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                     alert(data);
                     fetch_data();
                }
           })
      });
      function edit_data(id, text, column_name)
      {
           $.ajax({
                url:"edit.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                     alert(data);

                }
           });
      }
      $(document).on('blur', '.titre', function(){
           var id = $(this).data("id1");
           var titre = $(this).text();
           edit_data(id, titre, "titre");
      });
      $(document).on('blur', '.datereunion', function(){
           var id = $(this).data("id2");
           var datereunion = $(this).text();
           edit_data(id,datereunion, "datereunion");
      });
      $(document).on('blur', '.description', function(){
           var id = $(this).data("id3");
           var description = $(this).text();
           edit_data(id,description, "description");
      });
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){
           var id=$(this).data("id4");
           if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
           {
                $.ajax({
                     url:"delete.php",
                     method:"POST",
                     data:{id:id},
                     dataType:"text",
                     success:function(data){
                          alert(data);
                          fetch_data();
                     }
                });
           }
      });
 });
 </script>
```

select.php
This file allows me to display data on a table from the database

```
<?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "architecture");
 $output = '';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM archireunion ORDER BY datereunion DESC WHERE datereunion='".$_POST['madate']"'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive">
           <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>
                     <th width="40%">Titre</th>
                     <th width="40%">Date</th>
                     <th width="40%">Description</th>
                     <th width="10%">Delete</th>

                </tr>';
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
           $output .= '
                <tr>
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                     <td class="titre" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["titre"].'</td>
                     <td class="datereunion" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["datereunion"].'</td>
                     <td class="description" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["description"].'</td>

                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>
                </tr>
           ';
      }
      $output .= '
           <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td id="titre" contenteditable></td>
                <td id="datereunion" contenteditable></td>
                <td id="description" contenteditable></td>

                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>
           </tr>
      ';
 }
 else
 {
      $output .= '<tr>
                          <td colspan="4">Pas de réunion</td>
                     </tr>';[enter image description here][1]
 }
 $output .= '</table>
      </div>';
 echo $output;

 ?>
```

Comment: For one thing, the WHERE clause needs to go before the ORDER BY

Comment: mysqli knows nothing of whatever pages. It's PHP who is responsible for receiving variables.

Comment: Thank you iainn   when i put for example  :   $sql = "SELECT * FROM archireunion WHERE datereunion='1994-02-24' ORDER BY datereunion DESC"; it works but when i write     $sql = "SELECT * FROM archireunion WHERE datereunion='".$_POST['madate']"' ORDER BY datereunion DESC";  it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The select.php script is not getting the madate variable. You are calling it from the index.php JS function fetch_data but no parameters are set on that call.

Since the select.php is being called from the fetch_data function you must set the value of madate on that function:

```
function fetch_data()
{
    $.ajax({
            url:"select.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{madate: "<?=$_REQUEST['madate']?>"},
            success:function(data){
                 $('#live_data').html(data);
            }
       });
  }
```

Also, in the date.php file you are not setting the name of the variable, just the value, it should look like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="date" name="madate" />
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
</form>
```

Then the process would be like this:

- The date.php allows the user to pick a date. The date is sent to index.php as the madate parameter.
- In the index.php, you inject the value of madate in the fetch_data function, so that it is sent to the select.php script.
- The select.php script receives the madate variable and uses it to query the database.

By the way, your SQL code is open to evil injections, you must **always** use prepared statements when querying the database with data sent by users (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or sanitize any parameter you use in the query with mysqli_real_escape_string (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['madate']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM archireunion ORDER BY datereunion DESC WHERE datereunion='$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Comment: Thank you Koas, I made the changes but it still does not work, and i don't have any error

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM archireunion WHERE datereunion='madate' ORDER BY datereunion DESC";       is that the correct syntax?

Comment: I've update my answer with the PHP code you should use for the query.

Comment: Are you receiving the madate variable in select.php? Try print_r($_POST) as the first line in your select.php script and use the browser console to check the output of the AJAX call to select.php.

Comment: i don't know if select.php is receiving the madate variable, now when i try to replace $date with 2017-10-23 for example which exists on the database i don't get anything

Comment: how can i write print_r($_POST) in the select.php file?